# Desktop AIR app and Facebook login

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, air

I try using this lib https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/,
but when I call FacebookDesktop.init("820024968051122",loginHandler);
I get error:

```
code: 2500
message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
type: OAuthException
```

If I call FacebookDesktop.init("820024968051122",loginHandler,"test_user_token");
then all work fine, but where I get token if user is not log in?

Answer (score 0):

Well buddy, you can read the [documentation](http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html), where you can see that under `init` there is `login` method, stating: `[static] Opens a new login window so the current user can log in to Facebook.`

Comment: If I call login method I get Error: FacebookDesktop.init() needs to be called first.

Comment: As far as I can see, you can call init *without* token, and I guess you will get error *only* if you do a query. You should check if the user is logged in and call `login` if needed. If you simply get error without doing a query - contact project owner and report a bug. Basically as this is so much open source - just provide fake token and continue on :)

Comment: I find solution with HTMLLoader, but I need more native way. Second method using custom URL scheme of my app, open success Facebook page in a browser and listen callback from the browser. But I have no ready-made solution of this. Can you help?

Comment: Everything depends on the AIR extension you are using. I don't want to advertise anything, but I've already used [Distriqt](http://airnativeextensions.com/)'s Facebook extensions and they work like a charm! They've integrated the native SDK and therefore can provide you with native login dialogs. Other than that - what you've done is the only thing you've got (*except* searching for better ANE). Good luck! :)